# Unable to create a connection to a Database that is created by tunneling

Tags: database, robotframework, pymysql

I have a test case in Robot Framework where i have a tunnel created and using the local host and tunneled port i am trying to establish the Database connection and i am getting an error when i try to run.

```
Setup failed:
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype)")

Also teardown failed:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Tunnel Created -

```
ssh -L 13306:<DB host server Name>:3306 UserName@RemoteMachineHOstName
```

Robot Settings section-

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DatabaseLibrary
Test Setup  Connect To Database Using Custom Params  pymysql  'localhost', '13306', 'DBUSERNAME', 'DBPASSWORD', 'DBNAME'
Test Teardown  Disconnect From Database
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't look deep into the `Connect To Database Using Custom Params` keyword, but a few things about Robot Framework:

1. No need to use quotes to pass a string. Parameters are always passed as string.
   So don't pass `'localhost'`, just use `localhost`.
2. Parameters are separated by 2 or more spaces.
   ie, get rid of those commas `,`.

Try this:

```
Test Setup  Connect To Database Using Custom Params  pymysql  localhost  13306  DBUSERNAME  DBPASSWORD  DBNAME
```

Note the 2 spaces between each parameter.